# SSRS How to refer to detail values inside column groupings

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-tablix

I have a matrix with columns grouped by date, with only 2 dates. I want to add a third column with a percentage comparison between the 2 dates. How to refer to the the individual dates inside the date grouping?

[image]

This is the matrix design:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you guarantee there are only 2 dates, you can add a total column for each of the date groups and use the following expression:

```
=First(Fields!qtyE.Value)/Last(Fields!qtyE.Value)
```

Comment: This would only work (I think) if there was only a single record in the dataset query for each visible number in the report. Looking at the report design it appears that there is a sum() happening.

Comment: Yeah, you're right @AlanSchofield (although it could be a SUM of 1 record).

Comment: @AlanSchofield Indeed the sql query already aggregates it so there is only one record for each data point. The `Sum` is there just because ssrs puts it there by default.